# Find method in scala reflect by it's bytecode name

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect, scalameta

Is there a way to find a method by it's bytecode name?

For example, I would like to find a reference to `println(Object)` by string `"_root_.scala.Predef.println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V."`

Comment: I'm curious how you got into this situation (of needing or wanting to do this).

Comment: @SethTisue, I am working with **both** scalameta semantic api and scala-reflect and I'm currently in a situation where I have a `scala.meta.Symbol`, but want to call a scala-reflect API with it. I didn't find any straightforward way to convert `scala.meta.Symbol` to something what scala-reflect can understand easily. That is why I'm asking this.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no direct way** to do it.

You have to parse string to extract class name. Load class by name and iterate thru its method to find required method.